# Delete detached entity spring jpa Repository interface

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

I was reading that deleting detached entity will cause IllegalArgumentExcetpion, the entity should be managed to be removed. However , I'm using spring JPA repository interface and the delete is working on a detached entity , I have created new entity with the ID I want to delete and I got no exception. is there any document says we can delete detached entity in spring jpa ? I couldn't find official document.

Answer (score 0):

Before you can use repository.delete(entity) , you should call repository.find(entityID) to prevent "detached entity exception ".

Answer (score 0):

Every entity has id and you can delete deatached entity by id like

```
 @Modifying @Query("delete from OwnEntity e where e.id = :id")
 Long deleteById(@Param("id") Long id);
```